# In iOS 7 done button in number pad keyboard is absolutely ok but not in iOS 8. i didn't change anything but only update ios8

Tags: objective-c, ios8, uikeyboard

Error is - Can't find keyplane that supports type 4 for keyboard iPhone-Portrait-NumberPad; using 3876877096_Portrait_iPhone-Simple-Pad_Default

## define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v)  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)note
{
    
   // NSLog(@"keyboardwillshow");
    doneButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    doneButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 163, 106, 53);
    doneButton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = NO;
  
    [doneButton setTitle:@"Done" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [doneButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [doneButton addTarget:self action:@selector(dismissKeyboard1) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    
    if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0")) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
          //    UIView *keyboardView = [[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] lastObject] subviews] firstObject];
          //   [doneButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, keyboardView.frame.size.height - 53, 106, 53)];
          //    doneButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height-480)+163, 106, 53);
            
            doneButton.frame = CGRectMake(0,163, 106, 53);
            
            UIWindow* tempWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:1];
            UIView* keyboard;
            for(int i=0; i<[tempWindow.subviews count]; i++) {
                keyboard = [tempWindow.subviews objectAtIndex:i];
                //                    NSLog(@"%f",keyboard.frame.size.height);
                // keyboard found, add the button
                if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 3.2) {
                    if([[keyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIPeripheralHost"] == YES)
                        [keyboard addSubview:doneButton];
                } else {
                    if([[keyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIKeyboard"] == YES)
                        [keyboard addSubview:doneButton];
                }
            }
            
         
         
            
         //   [keyboardView addSubview:doneButton];
          //  [keyboardView bringSubviewToFront:doneButton];
            
            [UIView animateWithDuration:[[note.userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] floatValue]-.02
                                  delay:.0
                                options:[[note.userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] intValue]
                             animations:^{
                                 self.view.frame = CGRectOffset(self.view.frame, 0, 0);
                             } completion:nil];
        });
    }else {
        // locate keyboard view
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            UIWindow* tempWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:1];
            UIView* keyboard;
            for(int i=0; i<[tempWindow.subviews count]; i++) {
                keyboard = [tempWindow.subviews objectAtIndex:i];
                // keyboard view found; add the custom button to it
                if([[keyboard description] hasPrefix:@"UIKeyboard"] == YES)
                    [keyboard addSubview:doneButton];
            }
        });
    }
 
}
```

Comment: Could you add an error log or a written description of what is "not working" according? is it not displaying? is it crashing? Give as much informatoin as you can without being too broad or vague

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having trouble with this solution too,then i found this

[how to get keyboard location in ios 8 & add DONE button on numberPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26031798/how-to-get-keyboard-location-in-ios-8-add-done-button-on-numberpad)

You just add the addButtonToKeyboard method and call it in the textfieldEditingDidBegin delegate,you declare the button in the addButtonToKeyboard method too.

```
- (void)addButtonToKeyboard
{
// create custom button
self.doneButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
self.doneButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 163+44, 106, 53);
self.doneButton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = NO;
[self.doneButton setTag:67123];
[self.doneButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"doneup1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.doneButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"donedown1.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

[self.doneButton addTarget:self action:@selector(doneButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

// locate keyboard view
int windowCount = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] count];
if (windowCount < 2) {
    return;
}

UIWindow* tempWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:1];
UIView* keyboard;

for(int i = 0 ; i < [tempWindow.subviews count] ; i++)
{
    keyboard = [tempWindow.subviews objectAtIndex:i];
    // keyboard found, add the button

    if([[keyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIPeripheralHost"] == YES){
        UIButton* searchbtn = (UIButton*)[keyboard viewWithTag:67123];
        if (searchbtn == nil)//to avoid adding again and again as per my requirement (previous and next button on keyboard)
            [keyboard addSubview:self.doneButton];

    }//This code will work on iOS 8.0
    else if([[keyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIInputSetContainerView"] == YES){

        for(int i = 0 ; i < [keyboard.subviews count] ; i++)
        {
            UIView* hostkeyboard = [keyboard.subviews objectAtIndex:i];

            if([[hostkeyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIInputSetHost"] == YES){
                UIButton* donebtn = (UIButton*)[hostkeyboard viewWithTag:67123];
                if (donebtn == nil)//to avoid adding again and again as per my requirement (previous and next button on keyboard)
                    [hostkeyboard addSubview:self.doneButton];
            }
        }
    }
else{}
}
}
```

To hide it call the removeButtonFromKeyboard method and call it in the textfieldEditingDidEnd delegate.

```
- (void)removeButtonFromKeyboard
{
NSArray *arTemp = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows];
if ([arTemp count] <= 1) return;
UIWindow* tempWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:1];
UIView* keyboard;
for(int i=0; i<[tempWindow.subviews count]; i++)
{
    keyboard = [tempWindow.subviews objectAtIndex:i];
    // keyboard found, add the button
    if ([[keyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIPeripheralHost"] == YES)
    {
        for (id temp in keyboard.subviews)
        {
            if ([temp isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
            {
                UIButton *btnDone = (UIButton*) temp;
                [btnDone removeFromSuperview];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    //This code will work on iOS 8.0
    else if([[keyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIInputSetContainerView"] == YES)
    {
        for(int i = 0 ; i < [keyboard.subviews count] ; i++)
        {
            UIView* hostkeyboard = [keyboard.subviews objectAtIndex:i];
            if([[hostkeyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIInputSetHost"] == YES)
            {
                for (id temp in hostkeyboard.subviews)
                {
                    if ([temp isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
                    {
                        UIButton *btnNext = (UIButton*) temp;
                        [btnNext removeFromSuperview];
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else{}
}
}
```

You will still get the  Can't find keyplane that supports type 4 for keyboard iPhone-Portrait-NumberPad; using 3876877096_Portrait_iPhone-Simple-Pad_Default error but you can ignore it.

I recommend you try this,it worked for me,all credit goes to iGW