# how to get keyboard location in ios 8 & add DONE button on numberPad

Tags: keyboard, ios8

I am using  below code to get the keyboard location from view & add DONE button on it.But in ios 8 it is not able to get keyboard location & hence not add DONE button.

```
UIWindow *tempWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:1];

UIView *keyboard;

for (int i = 0; i < [tempWindow.subviews count]; i++)
{
    keyboard = [tempWindow.subviews objectAtIndex:i];
    // keyboard view found; add the custom button to it

    if ([[keyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIPeripheralHostView"] == YES)
    {
        [keyboard addSubview:doneButton];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The below code is for showing **"DONE"** button on NumberPad **iOS 8** also. 
I run this code in XCode-5.1.1 with **iOS 6/7/8 devices**. Its working perfectly.

I take the refrence from this link [Can't find keyplane that supports type 4 for keyboard iPhone-Portrait-NumberPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25842168/cant-find-keyplane-that-supports-type-4-for-keyboard-iphone-portrait-numberpad) given some code for add button on Number keyboard.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIButton *doneButton;
```

**AddButton**

```
- (void)addButtonToKeyboard
{
    if (!self.doneButton)
    {
        self.doneButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [self.doneButton addTarget:self action:@selector(doneButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }
    self.doneButton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = NO;
    [self.doneButton setTitle:@"DONE" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.doneButton.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0]];
    [self.doneButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.doneButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

    // locate keyboard view
    if ([[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] count] <= 1) return;
    UIWindow* tempWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:1];
    UIView* keyboard;
    for(int i=0; i<[tempWindow.subviews count]; i++)
    {
        keyboard = [tempWindow.subviews objectAtIndex:i];
        // keyboard found, add the button
        if ([[keyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIPeripheralHost"] == YES)
        {
            BOOL isPortrait = UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation);
            self.doneButton.frame = CGRectMake(((isPortrait)?0:-1),((int) (keyboard.frame.size.height*3)/4) + ((isPortrait)?0:1),(int) keyboard.frame.size.width/3-1, (isPortrait)?60:40);
            [keyboard addSubview:self.doneButton];
        }
        //This code will work on iOS 8.0
        else if([[keyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIInputSetContainerView"] == YES)
        {
            for(int i = 0 ; i < [keyboard.subviews count] ; i++)
            {
                UIView* hostkeyboard = [keyboard.subviews objectAtIndex:i];
                if([[hostkeyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIInputSetHost"] == YES)
                {
                    BOOL isPortrait = UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation);
                    self.doneButton.frame = CGRectMake(((isPortrait) ? 0 : -1),((int) (hostkeyboard.frame.size.height*3)/4) + ((isPortrait) ? 0 : 1),(int) hostkeyboard.frame.size.width/3-1, (isPortrait) ? 60 : 40);
                    [hostkeyboard addSubview:self.doneButton];
                }
            }
        }
        else{}
    }
}
```

**removeButtonFromKeyboard**

```
- (void)removeButtonFromKeyboard
{
    NSArray *arTemp = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows];
    if ([arTemp count] <= 1) return;
    UIWindow* tempWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:1];
    UIView* keyboard;
    for(int i=0; i<[tempWindow.subviews count]; i++)
    {
        keyboard = [tempWindow.subviews objectAtIndex:i];
        // keyboard found, add the button
        if ([[keyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIPeripheralHost"] == YES)
        {
            for (id temp in keyboard.subviews)
            {
                if ([temp isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
                {
                    UIButton *btnDone = (UIButton*) temp;
                    [btnDone removeFromSuperview];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        //This code will work on iOS 8.0
        else if([[keyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIInputSetContainerView"] == YES)
        {
            for(int i = 0 ; i < [keyboard.subviews count] ; i++)
            {
                UIView* hostkeyboard = [keyboard.subviews objectAtIndex:i];
                if([[hostkeyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIInputSetHost"] == YES)
                {
                    for (id temp in hostkeyboard.subviews)
                    {
                        if ([temp isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
                        {
                            UIButton *btnDone = (UIButton*) temp;
                            [btnDone removeFromSuperview];
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else{}
    }
}
```

Let me know any issues.

Update:
Testing on iOS 7.1, real device - the button is not being added unless the keyboard show animation has finished. The code below adds a delay to add button once the keyboard is fully visible:

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [self performSelector:@selector(addButtonToKeyboard) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.75];

}
```

Comment: Gr8 it worked, but when I change textfield from numpad to normal keyboard the done button appears in front of keyboard..what should I do?

Comment: You have to call removeButtonFromKeyboard in "textFieldShouldEndEditing" delegate method. That's it.

Comment: dude when I directly click on textfield done button gets hidden, and if I go clicking from downwards to upwards again it get vanished. What to do?

Comment: @iAnurag - Please follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25842168/cant-find-keyplane-that-supports-type-4-for-keyboard-iphone-portrait-numberpad It will fulfill all your needs.

Comment: i want to remove the done button and also the predictive text bar from the keyboard .i want to show only keyboard please help.

Comment: I did all this actions but done button is not clickable, can you help me?

Comment: Looks like it got broken again in iOS9. Do you have updated solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

- I did like "Alex-stone" but I can't to click custom button.
- My solution:

> //create DoneCustomReturnKeyButton to add into keyboard

```
 - (void)addDoneCustomReturnKeyButtonInKeyboard:(NSNotification *)notification
{
NSArray *arr = [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] lastObject] subviews];
if (arr.count > 0) {

    UIView *keyboardView = [arr objectAtIndex:0];
    float height;
    if ([[keyboardView description] hasPrefix:@"<UIPeripheralHost"] == YES) {
        height = (CGRectGetHeight(keyboardView.frame) -
                  CGRectGetHeight(self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame)) / 4;

        [self.doneCustomReturnKeyButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, keyboardView.frame.size.height - height,
                                                            keyboardView.frame.size.width/3 - 2, height)];
        [keyboardView addSubview:self.doneCustomReturnKeyButton];
    }
    //This code will work on iOS 8.0
    else if([[keyboardView description] hasPrefix:@"<UIInputSetContainerView"] == YES)
    {
        for(int i = 0 ; i < [keyboardView.subviews count] ; i++)
        {
            UIView* hostkeyboard = [keyboardView.subviews objectAtIndex:i];
            if([[hostkeyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIInputSetHost"] == YES)
            {
                UIButton* donebtn = (UIButton*)[hostkeyboard viewWithTag:67123];
                if (donebtn == nil)
                {
                    height = (CGRectGetHeight(hostkeyboard.frame) -
                              CGRectGetHeight(self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame)) / 4;

                    [self.doneCustomReturnKeyButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, keyboardView.frame.size.height - height,
                                                                        keyboardView.frame.size.width/3 - 2, height)];

                    [keyboardView addSubview:self.doneCustomReturnKeyButton];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
else {
    self.doneCustomReturnKeyButton.hidden = YES;
}
```

}

and create button.

```
 - (void)createDoneCustomReturnKeyButton
{
    self.doneCustomReturnKeyButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
    [self.doneCustomReturnKeyButton setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"NEXT", nil) forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.doneCustomReturnKeyButton.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:20]];
    self.doneCustomReturnKeyButton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = NO;
    self.doneCustomReturnKeyButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    [self.doneCustomReturnKeyButton setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [self.doneCustomReturnKeyButton addTarget:self
                                       action:@selector(doneCustomReturnKeyButtonAction:)
                             forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay here's a simple fix for getting 'done' button to show and work in my app in both iOS 9, iOS 8 and below when I got similar error. It could be observed after running an app and viewing it via 'View's Hierarchy' (i.e. clicking on the 'View Hierarchy' icon from Debug Area bar while app is running on *device* and inspecting your views in Storyboard), that the keyboard is presented on different windows in iOS 9 compared to iOS 8 and below versions and have to be accounted for.
**addButtonToKeyboard**

```
- (id)addButtonToKeyboard
{
if (!doneButton)
{
   // create custom button
    UIButton * doneButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    doneButton.frame = CGRectMake(-2, 163, 106, 53);
    doneButton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = NO;
    [doneButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"DoneUp.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [doneButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"DoneDown.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [doneButton addTarget:self action:@selector(saveNewLead:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}

NSArray *windows = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows];
//Check to see if running below iOS 9,then return the second window which bears the keyboard   
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] < 9.0) {
return windows[windows.count - 2];
}
else {
UIWindow* keyboardWithDoneButtonWindow = [ windows lastObject];
return keyboardWithDoneButtonWindow;
    }
}
```

And this is how you could **removeKeyboardButton** from keyboard if you want.

```
- (void)removeKeyboardButton {

id windowTemp = [self addButtonToKeyboard];

if (windowTemp) {

    for (UIView *doneButton in [windowTemp subviews]) {
        if ([doneButton isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
            [doneButton setHidden:TRUE];
        }
    }
  }
}
```

If you using UITextfieldsDelegeates methods, you can simply call the *addButtonToKeyboard* method in the textFieldDidBeginEditing delegate method and that should do it. Now if you toggling back and forth between NumberPad and Default keyboard, it is recommended you call the *removeKeyboardButton* in "textFieldShouldEndEditing" delegate method to prevent any mishaps.