# iOS 8.3 subview in native keyboard (UIInputSetHostView) doesn't respond to touches

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ios8.3

After recent iOS SDK 8.3 update, I'm unable to properly add subview to the native keyboard (UIInputSetHostView). Before the update I was using this solution (https://stackoverflow.com/a/26041697/1187451) and everything worked fine. However, at the moment this workaround doesn't work properly.. After adding a subview on top of the keyboard and trying to select the item, native keyboard's letters are being selected instead (Screenshot: http://grab.by/H3aY). If I got it right, apple has changed UIInputSetHostView's pointInside:withEvent: return value...

Basically, what I'm trying to do is something simmilar to facebook's messenger app, when user in the chat screen is able to select stickers that are displayed on top of the keyboard.

Maybe some of you know the way to do this?

The code which I'm using:

```
  UIWindow* tempWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:1];
UIView* keyboard;

for(int i=0; i<[tempWindow.subviews count]; i++)
{
    keyboard = [tempWindow.subviews objectAtIndex:i];

    if([[keyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIInputSetContainerView"] == YES)
    {
        for(int i = 0 ; i < [keyboard.subviews count] ; i++)
        {
            UIView* hostkeyboard = [keyboard.subviews objectAtIndex:i];
            if([[hostkeyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIInputSetHost"] == YES)
            {

                [hostkeyboard addSubview:stickersView];

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Adding subviews to native keyboards has never been supported. Either use the standard `inputAccessoryView` of a text field or text view, or write a custom keyboard. Any other hack is just going to break every time there is an iOS update.