# Adding custom button above iPhone numpad iOS9

Tags: iphone, keyboard, ios9

We all know how to add custom button (usually it's Done) above normal numeric pad on iPhone. There were few questions related to this:

[how to get keyboard location in ios 8 & add DONE button on numberPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26031798/how-to-get-keyboard-location-in-ios-8-add-done-button-on-numberpad/26041697#comment53001301_26041697)

[Can't find keyplane that supports type 4 for keyboard iPhone-Portrait-NumberPad; using 3876877096_Portrait_iPhone-Simple-Pad_Default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25842168/cant-find-keyplane-that-supports-type-4-for-keyboard-iphone-portrait-numberpad/25971098#comment53090580_25971098)

they work fine before iOS9. iOS9 broke that existing keyboard view hierarchy and above mentioned solutions don't work anymore. I've spend few hours trying to figure out the difference, and decided to post it here as it might be useful for other people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference from the solution that worked for iOS7-8 is the following:

```
// Note index 2 here! In pre-iOS8 keyboard view panel was under second window after UIWindow, in iOS9 - they put some other views on the place and shifted everything one element down.
UIWindow *tempWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows][2];
UIView *keyboard;
for (int i = 0; i < [tempWindow.subviews count]; i++)
{
    keyboard = [tempWindow.subviews objectAtIndex:i];
    // keyboard view found; add the custom button to it
    if ([[keyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIPeripheralHostView"] == YES)
    {
        [keyboard addSubview:doneButton];
    }

}
```

Comment: i have the same problem how can i get the UIKeyboard from the Window plaese advise in IOS9

Comment: Thanks for the help @sha i add view over the keyboard but now the problem is that the view i had over the keyboard is Uitableview when i click tableview row the keyboard button are pressed please advise.

Comment: @ManjitSingh: this is completely unrelated to keyboard and iOS9 question.

Comment: This is crashing with this Xcode 7 & iOS 9. Did you check that.

Comment: @Abhinav, where exactly does it crash?

Comment: It crashes on very first line as Windows does not have 3 objects in it. It is always best practice to check array size before fetching object from an index. Test once with Xcode 7 on iOS 9 and you would be able to get it.

Comment: I tested Xcode 7.0.1 and iOS simulator iOS9. When looking at sharedApplication.windows list I get 3 objects: UIWindow, UITextEffectsWindow, and UIRemoteKeyboardWindow

Comment: It works, button displayed over the keyboard above code.. But the button action not triggered.. any one face this issue ?